# Need help in this hypothesis in general topology

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that if every finite subset of a topological space $X$ is closed and every subset of $X$ is compact, then, $X$ has the discrete topology.

I couldn't disprove or prove this statement and I need this result to prove a question which I'm struggling with.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider for instance the cofinite topology on a non-finite set. The closed sets are precisely the finite ones and every subset is compact.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Zariski topology on the real line is a counter example.